# java string to int not doing anything

Tags: java

I have a .txt file which houses data as seen below. What I want to do is read from the file line by line then convert it to an int and display the result to screen.

The first system out line works fine, no problems their. The second however doesn't even print to screen. I guess theirs a issue with the string converting to int?

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("f.txt"))) 
                    {
                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line); //does show
                        int change2Int = Integer.parseInt(line);
                        System.out.println(change2Int); //doesnt show
                        mp.getDataForDisplay(line);
                    }
                    }
                catch (Exception expe)
                {
expe.printStackTrace();
                }
```

FIle:

```
0
1
4
2
5
```

The error it produces is a number format exception error.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0 "
```

Comment: You are swallowing the exception. In the catch block, put `expe.printStackTrace()` and edit the error into your question

Comment: swallowing the exception is not good, but it is not the problem here as looping is still happening.  I guess this is not the code that is producing the output.

Comment: @ScaryWombat - What are you basing that on?  From the post it's not clear whether or not the loop is iterating more than once.  Also, shot in the dark, but I'd suggest trying `Integer.parseInt(line.trim())` to ensure that whitespace characters aren't tripping up your parse.

Comment: Probably you have whitespaces or another character that breaks the conversion.

Comment: You're trying to parse a `String` to an `int`, but the `String` doesn't contain only digits. Is there anything in your file after `5`? Show the file content please

Comment: The file contents their. Literally its just those numbers

Comment: @aroth Sorry, you are right. It says `File:` NOT `output`

Comment: @aroth your line did justice! could you post it as an answer so i can mark it as a solution

Comment: try removing the " "(space) in your file where you list the numbers

Comment: The lesson to be learned here is to never ignore exceptions as you're doing. It's the programming equivalent of driving with your eyes closed and **often** results in disastrous results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NumberFormatException` that you're getting says what the problem is.  Your input file also has some trailing whitespace characters in it, which is causing the parse to fail.

A simple way to prevent leading/trailing whitespace from tripping up your parse is to `trim()` your string before you attempt to parse it, like:

```
int change2Int = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());
```

As a general principle, it's a good idea [to be permissive about what your program accepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) as input, so that it can't be derailed by things like misplaced 'space' characters and other common human errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your input string is "0 " which means there's a space. Use `trim()` before parsing. `trim()` is used to remove whitespace such as spaces.

eg:

```
int change2Int = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());
```